# Add new item top on RecyclerView

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I'm added Comment feature in my Blog App. I Retrive comments by **RecyclerView** and made `orderBy("timestamp")` as newer comment show top.

I use Firebase Firestore, after retrive all comments. **When user post new comments, I want the comment show at Top**. but Generally the comment added Bottom of list so it's basically show at bottom of recyclerview.

I used the below code to show **new comment top** But unfortunetly all comments go to `Else` statement instead of new comment:

```
if (isFirstLoad) {
    userList.add(userInfo);
    commentList.add(commentInfo);
}else{
    userList.add(0, userInfo);
    commentList.add(0, commentInfo);
}
```

The whole code for retreive comments:

```
Query query = db.collection("BlogPosts/" + postId + "/Comments").orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

        if (queryDocumentSnapshots!=null && !queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){

            for (DocumentChange doc: queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){
                if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){

                    final BlogCommentInfo commentInfo = doc.getDocument().toObject(BlogCommentInfo.class);

                    String BlogUserId = doc.getDocument().getString("user_id");
                    db.collection("Users").document(BlogUserId).get().addOnCompleteListener(CommentActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                            if (task.isSuccessful()){

                                UsersInfo userInfo = task.getResult().toObject(UsersInfo.class);

                                if (isFirstLoad) {
                                    userList.add(userInfo);
                                    commentList.add(commentInfo);
                                }else{
                                    userList.add(0, userInfo);
                                    commentList.add(0, commentInfo);
                                }
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this, "Error: "+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });


                }
            }

        }
        isFirstLoad = false;
    }
});
```

**Please help me to solve this.**

**Or Let me know if you have any others way to show the newer comment top of recyclerview.**

Comment: you have severely nested code which make the code super hard to read and maintain. Look into inverting if statements, returning early and delegating execution to separate methods or classes

Comment: Here I use Run sub-query in Main query. Main query send all information to adapter and sub query send only users info from Firebase User Uid. Can you provide a solution? @TimCastelijns

Comment: you have no idea what I just said do you

Comment: may I got you, thanks @TimCastelijns

Answer (score 0):

***Simply Hit query for the timestamp in ACCENDING order:***

**change your query from-**

> Query query = db.collection("BlogPosts/" + postId +
>   "/Comments").orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

**TO-**

> Query query = db.collection("BlogPosts/" + postId +
>   "/Comments").orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

**Or reverse your commentList**

Comment: Acctually problem isn't there. I tested and all blog orderby works function works well. I only want, When User add new comment the comment show at top istead of bottom. so I use, 
`if (isFirstLoad) {
    userList.add(userInfo);
    commentList.add(commentInfo);
}else{
    userList.add(0, userInfo);
    commentList.add(0, commentInfo);
}`
but unfortunetly `isLoadFirst` will be `false` before retreive all comments.

Comment: instead of isFirstLoad flag you can check the userList & CommentList is empty or null

Comment: first time the list will be empty

Comment: Yes I can do this. But without any bollean veriable how I can do this? After load 1st comment, the list wont be empty.